# Mandar a llamar un FXML en javaFX

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

Buenas noches de antemano pido una disculpa por si la pregunta suena un poco tonta pero soy nuevo en este tipo de trabajos, actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto de javafx en visual utilizando SceneBuilder, estoy trabajando con varios fxml, en el siguiente fracmento del codigo es donde puse una sentencia para mandar a llamar un fxml dependiendo del tipo que se mande a llamar.

```
while (rs.next()){
        tipoUsuario = rs.getString("tipoUsuario");
    }
    if (tipoUsuario.equals("administrador")) {
        
    }
    if (tipoUsuario.equals("Cajero")){

    }
```

lo que no se es como puedo mandar a llamar los fxml,
los nombres de dichos archivos son
MenuAdmin.fxml y
MenuVendedor.fxml, alguna sugerencia de como puedo mandar a llamarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear el siguiente método que muestra cualquier archivo FXML:

```
public void showFXML(String FXMLName) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(FXMLName + ".fxml"));
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Luego, invoca el método cuando sea necesario:

```
while (rs.next()) {
   tipoUsuario = rs.getString("tipoUsuario");
}

if (tipoUsuario.equals("administrador")) {
   showFXML("MenuAdmin");
} else if (tipoUsuario.equals("Cajero")) {
   showFXML("MenuVendedor");
}
```